# Type '({ note, onBlockClick }: NoteProps) => void' is not assignable to type 'FC<NoteProps>'. Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'ReactNode'.ts

Tags: reactjs, typescript, electron-react-boilerplate

i am building a component to render a data object to my main page in react typescript. while implementing a functionality change, i received error in my code editor.

1. Type '({ note, onBlockClick }: NoteProps) => void' is not assignable to type 'FC'.
   Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'ReactNode'.ts(2322)
   const NoteComponent: React.FC
   at: const NoteComponent: React.FC = ({ note, onBlockClick }) => {
2. '}' expected.ts(1005)
   Note.tsx(22, 72): The parser expected to find a '}' to match the '{' token here.
   at: export default NoteComponent;

since there is no such issue visible to me, related to the errors, as i am returning something from the function, so the function cannot be void. also, for the issue in last line, there is no opening bracket or any bracket missing to be closed.

```
import { useState } from "react";
import React from "react";
import "./Note.css";

import { Notebook, Block, Section } from "renderer/models/notebook";

interface NoteProps {
  // note: {
  //   id: string;
  //   heading: string;
  //   blocks: Block[];
  //   sections: Section[];
  //   file_name?: string;
  //   created_at?: string;
  //   version?: number;
  // };
  note: Notebook;
  onBlockClick?: (blockId: string) => void;
}

const NoteComponent: React.FC<NoteProps> = ({ note, onBlockClick }) => {

  // render block------------------------------------------------------------------------

  const [showTextArea, setShowTextArea] = useState(false);
  const [activeBlockId, setActiveBlockId] = useState(""); // To track which block is being edited
  const [inputText, setInputText] = useState(""); // State to manage input text for new block
  // const handleAddBlockClick = (blockId: string) => {
  //   // You can perform any desired actions here, like showing the text area
  //   setShowTextArea(true);
  // };
  const handleInputTextChange = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLTextAreaElement>) => {
    setInputText(event.target.value);
  };

  const handleSaveNewBlock = () => {
    // Implement the logic to save the new block based on activeBlockId and inputText
    // You can update the blocks state or make an API call here
    setShowTextArea(false); // Hide the text area after saving
    setInputText(""); // Reset input text
  };

  const handleBlockClick = (blockId: string) => {
    // Call the onBlockClick prop with the blockId
    if (onBlockClick) {
      onBlockClick(blockId);
    }
  };

  // render subsections---------------------------------------------------------------------------------


  // const [subSectionsExpanded, setSubSectionsExpanded] = useState(false);
  const [subSectionsIsEditing, setSubSectionsIsEditing] = useState<boolean[]>([]);
  const [subSectionsEditedTitles, setSubSectionsEditedTitles] = useState<string[]>([]);
  // const [subSectionsEditedTitle, setSubSectionsEditedTitle] = useState("");

  // render sections----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


  // const [sectionsExpanded, setSectionsExpanded] = useState(false);
  const [sectionsIsEditing, setSectionsIsEditing] = useState<boolean[]>([]);
  const [sectionseditedTitles, setSectionseditedTitles] = useState<string[]>([]); // Array of edited titles
  // const [sectionseditedTitle, setSectionseditedTitle] = useState("");

  // ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------



  const renderBlocks = (blocks?: Block[] | []) => {



    if (!blocks || blocks.length === 0) {
      return null;
    }
    return (
      <div className="notebook-blocks">
      {blocks.map((block) => (
        <div key={block.id} className="notebook-block" onClick={() => handleBlockClick(block.id)}>
          <p className="notebook-block-text"
          // onClick={() => handleAddBlockClick(block.id)}
          >
            {block.text}
            {/* <span
              className="add-block-text"
            >
              Add Block
            </span> */}
          </p>
          {showTextArea && activeBlockId === block.id && (
            <div className="text-area-container">
              <textarea
                className="new-block-input-textarea"
                placeholder="Enter block content..."
                value={inputText}
                onChange={handleInputTextChange}
              />
              {/* Add a button or icon to save the new block */}
              {/* <button onClick={handleSaveNewBlock}>Save Block</button> */}
            </div>
          )}
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
    );
  };

  const renderSubSections = (subSections?: Section[] | [] ) => {

    // const toggleExpansion = () => {
    //   setSubSectionsExpanded(!subSectionsExpanded);
    // };
    const toggleEdit = (subsectionIndex: number) => {
      const updatedEditingArray = [...subSectionsIsEditing];
      updatedEditingArray[subsectionIndex] = !updatedEditingArray[subsectionIndex];
      setSubSectionsIsEditing(updatedEditingArray);

      if (subSections && subSections[subsectionIndex]) {
      // Reset edited title to the original sub-section heading when toggling edit mode
      const updatedTitlesArray = [...subSectionsEditedTitles];
      updatedTitlesArray[subsectionIndex] = subSections[subsectionIndex].heading;
      setSubSectionsEditedTitles(updatedTitlesArray);
    };


    const handleCrossClick = (subsectionIndex: number) => {
      if (subSections && subSections.length > subsectionIndex && subSections[subsectionIndex]) {
      const updatedTitlesArray = [...subSectionsEditedTitles];
      updatedTitlesArray[subsectionIndex] = subSections[subsectionIndex].heading;
      setSubSectionsEditedTitles(updatedTitlesArray);
      }
      toggleEdit(subsectionIndex);
    };


    const handleTickClick = (subsectionIndex: number) => {
      // You might want to perform an action here to save the edited title
      toggleEdit(subsectionIndex);
    };

    // const toggleEdit = () => {
    //   setSubSectionssEditing(!subSectionsIsEditing);
    // };

    // const handleCrossClick = (subsection:any) => {
    //   setSubSectionsEditedTitle(subsection.heading);
    //   toggleEdit();
    // };

    // const handleTickClick = () => {
    //   // You might want to perform an action here to save the edited title
    //   toggleEdit();
    // };

    if (!subSections || subSections.length === 0) {
      return null;
    }
    return (
      <div className="notebook-sub-sections">
        {subSections.map((subsection, subsectionIndex) => (
          <div key={subsection.id} className="notebook-sub-section">
            <div
              className="notebook-sub-section-heading"
              // onClick={toggleExpansion}
            >
              {subSectionsIsEditing[subsectionIndex] ? (
                <div className="edit-mode">
                  <input
                    type="text"
                    value={subSectionsEditedTitles[subsectionIndex]}
                    onChange={(e) =>{ const updatedTitlesArray = [...subSectionsEditedTitles];
                      updatedTitlesArray[subsectionIndex] = e.target.value;
                      setSubSectionsEditedTitles(updatedTitlesArray);
                    }}
                  />
                  <div className="icon-tick" onClick={() => handleTickClick(subsectionIndex)}>
                    &#x2714;
                  </div>
                  <div className="icon-cross" onClick={() => handleCrossClick(subsectionIndex)}>
                    &#x2716;
                  </div>
                </div>
              ) : (
                <div className="normal-mode">
                  {subSectionsEditedTitles[subsectionIndex]}
                  <div className="edit-icon" onClick={() => toggleEdit(subsectionIndex)}>
                    ✎
                  </div>
                </div>
              )}
              {/* {subsection.heading} */}
            </div>

            {renderBlocks(subsection.blocks)}
            {renderSubSections(subsection.sub_sections)}
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  };

  const renderSections = () => {

    // const toggleExpansion = () => {
    //   setSectionsExpanded(!sectionsExpanded);
    // };
    const toggleEdit = (sectionIndex: number) => {
      const updatedEditingArray = [...sectionsIsEditing];
      updatedEditingArray[sectionIndex] = !updatedEditingArray[sectionIndex];
      setSectionsIsEditing(updatedEditingArray);

      // Reset edited title to the original section heading when toggling edit mode
      const updatedTitlesArray = [...sectionseditedTitles];
      updatedTitlesArray[sectionIndex] = note.sections[sectionIndex].heading;
      setSectionseditedTitles(updatedTitlesArray);
    };

    const handleCrossClick = (sectionIndex: number) => {
      const updatedTitlesArray = [...sectionseditedTitles];
      updatedTitlesArray[sectionIndex] = note.sections[sectionIndex].heading;
      setSectionseditedTitles(updatedTitlesArray);

      toggleEdit(sectionIndex);
    };

    const handleTickClick = (sectionIndex: number) => {
      // You might want to perform an action here to save the edited title
      toggleEdit(sectionIndex);
    };

    // const toggleEdit = () => {
    //   setSectionsIsEditing(!sectionsIsEditing);
    // };

    // const handleCrossClick = (section:any) => {
    //   setSectionseditedTitle(section.heading);
    //   toggleEdit();
    // };

    // const handleTickClick = () => {
    //   // You might want to perform an action here to save the edited title
    //   toggleEdit();
    // };

    return (
      <div className="notebook-sections">
        {note.sections.map((section, index) => (
          <div key={section.id} className="notebook-section">
            <div className="notebook-section-heading"
            // onClick={toggleExpansion}
            >
              {sectionsIsEditing[index]  ? (
                <div className="edit-mode">
                  <input
                    type="text"
                    value={sectionseditedTitles[index]}
                    onChange={(e) => {
                      const updatedTitlesArray = [...sectionseditedTitles];
                      updatedTitlesArray[index] = e.target.value;
                      setSectionseditedTitles(updatedTitlesArray);
                    }}
                  />
                  <div className="icon-tick" onClick={() => handleTickClick(index)}>
                    &#x2714;
                  </div>
                  <div className="icon-cross" onClick={() => handleCrossClick(index)}>
                    &#x2716;
                  </div>
                </div>
              ) : (
                <div className="normal-mode">
                  {sectionseditedTitles[index]}
                  <div className="edit-icon" onClick={() => toggleEdit(index)}>
                    ✎
                  </div>
                </div>
              )}
              {/* {section.heading} */}
            </div>
            {renderBlocks(section.blocks)}
            {renderSubSections(section.sub_sections)}
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  };

  return (
    <div className="notebook-nested-view">
      {/* <h2 className="notebook-notebook-heading">{note.heading}</h2> */}
      {renderBlocks(note.blocks)}
      {renderSections()}
    </div>
  );
};
export default NoteComponent;
```

Comment: Show the code where you pass the props to `NoteComponent`

Comment: @RobinThomas
            <div className="notes">
              {/* {notes.map((note) => ( */}
              <NoteComponent note={notes} onBlockClick={handleBlockClick} />
              {/* ))} */}
            </div>

Comment: i cant paste the full code here in comment

Comment: Not in comment. Edit your question and add it there. Also, shall be good if you have a github link having the issue